# Unhandled rejection in Bluebird

Tags: javascript, bluebird

I have the following code.  It works fine when `f2` throws no error.

If there is an error, it generates an `Unhandled rejection Error`.

What's the proper way to rewrite the code to avoid `Unhandled rejection Error` and propagate it correctly to `catch` in `f1`?

```
let Bluebird = require('bluebird'),
    mkdirp = Bluebird.promisify(require('mkdirp')),
    request = Bluebird.promisify(require('request')),
    writeFile = Bluebird.promisify(require('fs').writeFile);

function f1() {
    .........
    f2(path, fileName, options).then(.....).catch(....); 
}

function f2(path, fileName, options) {
    p = mkdirp(path).then(request(options).then(res => {
        if (res[0].statusCode === 200) {
            writeFile(fileName, res[0].body);
            return res[0].body;
        } else {
            throw new Error(res[0].statusCode + ': ' + res[0].body);
        }
    }));
    return p;
}
```

Comment: In `f2`, you are assigning a value to `p`. What is `p`, and how are you calling `.then()` on the return value of `f2` if it doesn't return anything?

Comment: @JLRishe sorry, I introduced an error trimming down the code.  fixed now.

Comment: For what it's worth, in bluebird 3.0 that is coming out in a few weeks you would have gotten a warning

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I got lost in the number of parenthesis and didn't notice after a long day that instead of chaining I was actually passing a promise into then, so warnings will be very useful

Comment: @kyrylkov and indeed - bluebird 3.0 does that :) You get warnings in common pitfalls like passing a non-function to `then`. You can check it out by cloning and building the 3.0 branch of the librar.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I did see Petka's post about warnings in 3.0 earlier today.  Didn't think I was  a client for them :)

Comment: @kyrylkov the philosophy of bluebird is to be extremely pragmatic and to favour actual issues that users have. If you have any more issues feel free to ask - we guarantee an answer here on Stack Overflow (if your question is in an acceptable shape), response so bug reports on GH and good care. You most definitely are a client :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing a promise into `.then()` in `f2`. `.then()` will ignore anything that is not a function, so all that `f2` is really returning is a promise for `mkdirp(this.path)` and that's a big bug for a few reasons. If an error is thrown in `request(options)`'s `then` handler, then there will be nothing to handle it.

Also, you are not doing anything to handle a possible error from `writeFile`. If you call `writeFile`, you either need to return a promise chain that includes it, or add logic to handle it within `f2`.

Since it looks like you can run `mkdirp()` and `request()` in parallel here, but you are not using the result of `mkdirp()` I would say this is the way to go:

```
function f2(path, fileName, options) {
    var p = mkdirp(path).return(request(options)).then(res => {
        if (res[0].statusCode === 200) {
            return writeFile(fileName, res[0].body)
            .return(res[0].body);
        } else {
            throw new Error(res[0].statusCode + ': ' + res[0].body);
        }
    });
    return p;
}
```

Comment: The error I'm having is due to `throw new Error(res[0].statusCode + ': ' + res[0].body);`, not `writeFile`.  I have the error only when `else` branch in `f2` gets executed.

Comment: @kyrylkov Yes, my modification should account for both of those. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, I have.  It still shows up when `throw new Error(res[0].statusCode + ': ' + res[0].body);` gets executed.

Comment: @kyrylkov In that case I'm not sure. Did you copy my code exactly, or did you merge it into your existing code? If it's the latter, could you show us the updated code with my modifications (perhaps in PasteBin)?

Comment: Check it out http://pastebin.com/P6FjTLc9  The problem is NOT with `writeFile`.  Even when I remove it, the `else` clause causes the error

Comment: @kyrylkov Sorry, could you show me the whole code, with all of `f2` and the call to `f2`? I believe you when you that the error in the `else` is the one being thrown. I'd just like to see everything in context.

Comment: I was able to fix it.  You set me on the right path.

Comment: Coming in late: Did the solution involve putting a promise in f2? (If you remember so much later!)